# Multithreaded deserialization using BinaryFormatter

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, deserialization

Multithreading deserialization using BinaryFormatter or MessagePack is not giving me the performence boost I expect and I'm trying to understand why. Deserializing all chunks at the same time is around 5 times slower than deserializing 1 chunk for this setup.

Here is my test code with different types of multithreading. Tasks, Threads and ParallelForEach is used and the fastest by far is Threads.

The chunks are read in before performing the deserialization meaning no IO bound work is done and the chunks are split into amount of cores I have.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace SerializerDeserializeTests
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int threads = 8;
            int entries = 500000;
            string directory = "data";
            if(!Directory.Exists(directory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);

                Hashtable hashtable = GenerateHashtable(entries);
                List<Hashtable> chunks = ChunkHashtable(hashtable, threads);
                Export(chunks, directory);
            }
            else
            {
                Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
                stopwatch.Start();

                List<byte[]> chunks = Directory.GetFiles(directory).Select(File.ReadAllBytes).ToList();

                Console.WriteLine("Read: " + stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
                stopwatch.Stop();

                DeserializeParallelForEach(chunks).Clear();
                DeserializeParallelForEachOneChunk(chunks).Clear();
                DeserializeTasks(chunks).Clear();
                DeserializeTasksOneChunk(chunks).Clear();
                DeserializeThreads(chunks).Clear();
                DeserializeThreadsOneChunk(chunks).Clear();
            }
        }

        public static List<Hashtable> DeserializeThreadsOneChunk(List<byte[]> chunks)
        {
            chunks = new List<byte[]>() { chunks[0] };
            Console.WriteLine("----- DeserializeThreadsOneChunk -----");
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();

            ConcurrentBag<Hashtable> hashtables = new ConcurrentBag<Hashtable>();
            List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
            foreach (byte[] chunk in chunks)
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(chunk))
                    {
#pragma warning disable SYSLIB0011 // Type or member is obsolete
                        hashtables.Add((Hashtable)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream));
#pragma warning restore SYSLIB0011 // Type or member is obsolete
                    }
                });

                threads.Add(thread);
                thread.Start();
            }

            foreach (var thread in threads)
                thread.Join();

            Console.WriteLine("Deserialize: " + stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
            stopwatch.Stop();

            return hashtables.ToList();
        }
        public static List<Hashtable> DeserializeThreads(List<byte[]> chunks)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("----- DeserializeThreads -----");
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();

            ConcurrentBag<Hashtable> hashtables = new ConcurrentBag<Hashtable>();
            List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
            foreach (byte[] chunk in chunks)
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(chunk))
                    {
#pragma warning disable SYSLIB0011 // Type or member is obsolete
                        hashtables.Add((Hashtable)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream));
#pragma warning restore SYSLIB0011 // Type or member is obsolete
                    }
                });

                threads.Add(thread);
                thread.Start();
            }

            foreach (var thread in threads)
                thread.Join();

            Console.WriteLine("Deserialize: " + stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
            stopwatch.Stop();

            return hashtables.ToList();
        }

        public static List<Hashtable> DeserializeTasksOneChunk(List<byte[]> chunks)
        {
            chunks = new List<byte[]>() { chunks[0] };
            Console.WriteLine("----- DeserializeTasksOneChunk -----");
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();

            List<Task<Hashtable>> tasks = new List<Task<Hashtable>>();
            foreach (byte[] chunk in chunks)
            {
                Task<Hashtable> task = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(chunk))
                    {
#pragma warning disable SYSLIB0011 // Type or member is obsolete
                        return (Hashtable)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
#pragma warning restore SYSLIB0011 // Type or member is obsolete
                    }
                });

                tasks.Add(task);
            }

            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

            Console.WriteLine("Deserialize: " + stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
            stopwatch.Stop();

            return tasks.Select(x => x.Result).ToList();
        }
        public static List<Hashtable> DeserializeTasks(List<byte[]> chunks)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("----- DeserializeTasks -----");
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();

            List<Task<Hashtable>> tasks = new List<Task<Hashtable>>();
            foreach (byte[] chunk in chunks)
            {
                Task<Hashtable> task = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(chunk))
                    {
#pragma warning disable SYSLIB0011 // Type or member is obsolete
                       return (Hashtable)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
#pragma warning restore SYSLIB0011 // Type or member is obsolete
                    }
                });

                tasks.Add(task);
            }

            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

            Console.WriteLine("Deserialize: " + stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
            stopwatch.Stop();

            return tasks.Select(x => x.Result).ToList();
        }

        public static List<Hashtable> DeserializeParallelForEachOneChunk(List<byte[]> chunks)
        {
            chunks = new List<byte[]>() { chunks[0] };
            Console.WriteLine("----- DeserializeParallelForEachOneChunk -----");
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();

            ConcurrentBag<Hashtable> hashtables = new ConcurrentBag<Hashtable>();
            Parallel.ForEach(chunks, (chunk) =>
            {
                BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(chunk))
                {
#pragma warning disable SYSLIB0011 // Type or member is obsolete
                    hashtables.Add((Hashtable)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream));
#pragma warning restore SYSLIB0011 // Type or member is obsolete
                }
            });

            Console.WriteLine("Deserialize: " + stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
            stopwatch.Stop();

            return hashtables.ToList();
        }
        public static List<Hashtable> DeserializeParallelForEach(List<byte[]> chunks)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("----- DeserializeParallelForEach -----");
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();

            ConcurrentBag<Hashtable> hashtables = new ConcurrentBag<Hashtable>();
            Parallel.ForEach(chunks, (chunk) => 
            {
                BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(chunk))
                {
#pragma warning disable SYSLIB0011 // Type or member is obsolete
                    hashtables.Add((Hashtable)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream));
#pragma warning restore SYSLIB0011 // Type or member is obsolete
                }
            });

            Console.WriteLine("Deserialize: " + stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
            stopwatch.Stop();

            return hashtables.ToList();
        }

        public static void Export(List<Hashtable> chunks, string directory)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exporting chunks");
            foreach(Hashtable chunk in chunks)
            {
                BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(directory + "\\chunk-" + Guid.NewGuid() + ".dat", FileMode.Create))
                {
                    using(BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
                    {
#pragma warning disable SYSLIB0011 // Type or member is obsolete
                        binaryFormatter.Serialize(binaryWriter.BaseStream, chunk);
#pragma warning restore SYSLIB0011 // Type or member is obsolete
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public static List<Hashtable> ChunkHashtable(Hashtable hashtable, int numberOfChunks)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Chunking hashtable");
            int chunkSize = hashtable.Count / numberOfChunks;

            
            int remainder = hashtable.Count % numberOfChunks;

            
            var chunks = new List<Hashtable>(numberOfChunks);

            
            IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator = hashtable.GetEnumerator();
            int elementsAdded = 0;

            
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChunks; i++)
            {
               
                var chunk = new Hashtable();
                chunks.Add(chunk);

                
                int chunkSizeWithRemainder = chunkSize + (i < remainder ? 1 : 0);

                
                for (int j = 0; j < chunkSizeWithRemainder && elementsAdded < hashtable.Count; j++)
                {
                    enumerator.MoveNext();
                    chunk.Add(enumerator.Key, enumerator.Value);
                    elementsAdded++;
                }
            }

            return chunks;
        }
        public static Hashtable GenerateHashtable(int length)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Generating hashtable");
            Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                hashtable.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + i, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            }

            return hashtable;
        }
    }
}
```

Result: Hashtable + BinaryFormatter

```
Read: 0,0298205
----- DeserializeParallelForEach -----
Deserialize: 0,5175991
----- DeserializeParallelForEachOneChunk -----
Deserialize: 0,0809796
----- DeserializeTasks -----
Deserialize: 0,4418913
----- DeserializeTasksOneChunk -----
Deserialize: 0,193335
----- DeserializeThreads -----
Deserialize: 0,3709102
----- DeserializeThreadsOneChunk -----
Deserialize: 0,0767091
```

What I'm expecting is it should take the same amount of time to deserialize all chunks as one chunk.

Note: I know that BinaryFormatter shouldn't be used anymore but for my case it's fine.

Note2: MessagePack is even slower than BinaryFormatter and thus not included in my tests.

Update: Result for Dictionary<string,string> + BinaryFormatter. A lot slower.

```
----- DeserializeParallelForEach -----
Deserialize: 1,0663033
----- DeserializeParallelForEachOneChunk -----
Deserialize: 0,2345796
----- DeserializeTasks -----
Deserialize: 1,2000186
----- DeserializeTasksOneChunk -----
Deserialize: 0,2540234
----- DeserializeThreads -----
Deserialize: 1,2881502
----- DeserializeThreadsOneChunk -----
Deserialize: 0,196688
```

Update 2: Result for Dictionary<string,string> + Protobuf. A lot faster
than Dictionary<string,string> + BinaryFormatter and Hashtable + BinaryFormatter but still not as fast as expected.

```
----- DeserializeThreadsProtobuf -----
Deserialize: 0,2851767
----- DeserializeThreadsOneChunkProtobuf -----
Deserialize: 0,0720033
----- DeserializeParallelForEachProtobuf -----
Deserialize: 0,2275362
----- DeserializeParallelForEachOneChunkProtobuf -----
Deserialize: 0,0479956
----- DeserializeTasksProtobuf -----
Deserialize: 0,2434543
----- DeserializeTasksOneChunkProtobuf -----
Deserialize: 0,0314671
```

Comment: 1. Drop the BinaryFormatter. [It is broken and cannot be fixed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide). 2. When doing benchmarks, use [BenchmarkDotnet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/) to get usable figures.

Comment: Don't use BinaryFormatter in the first place. [BinaryFormatter is beyond obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/serialization/5.0/binaryformatter-serialization-obsolete) - it's being removed from .NET entirely because [it's insecure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide). Recent .NET versions removed functionality, raised warnings to errors  and .NET 9 is expected to remove it completely

Comment: _"I know that BinaryFormatter shouldn't be used anymore but for my case it's fine."_ - pretty sure, it's not.

Comment: _"What I'm expecting is it should take the same amount of time to deserialize all chunks as one chunk."_ - how did you come to that expectation?

Comment: *overlooking* the `BinaryFormatter` thing (they're not wrong, though, and this *will* block you from .NET 9 onwards); can you highlight exactly what numbers are concerning you? your expectation vs reality thing isn't entirely clear to me; is your point "I have 8 chunks, deseralization of independent data should be trivially parallelizable, this should be 8 times faster to process all chunks in parallel"? and if so: which numbers are you comparing? I want to be 100% sure I'm clear on the question

Comment: (additional to the above about "this *will* block you from .NET 9 onwards"; if you run this code on .NET 9 (edit: or .NET 8 ?), you get `System.NotSupportedException` "BinaryFormatter serialization and deserialization are disabled within this application. See https://aka.ms/binaryformatter for more information.") - happy to help understand the actual performance thing if you supply the additional context, though; and happy to advise on alternatives

Comment: ^^ where the first thing to understand would be: Parallelization comes with overhead. That is: expect to see if a single operation takes X amount of time that N concurrently executed instances of that operation probably take X + c amount of time, where c should be < X (given that all of the N operations _actually are_ executed concurrently).

Comment: @Fildor "What I'm expecting is it should take the same amount of time to deserialize all chunks as one chunk." - how did you come to that expectation?" well if it takes x seconds to do one chunk then doing 8 chunks on 8 different threads should take x seconds as well. That's how I understand multithreading.

Comment: @MarcGravell I don't really know what else to add, I'm trying to deserialize faster by using multithreading. By splitting the data into chunks and processing each chunk on a different thread it should take the same amount of time as processing one chunk on one thread. Maybe BinaryFormatter or MemoryStream is blocking the other threads somehow. And I would gladly hear other alternatives. My goal is to import a hashtable as fast as possible from a file without re-creating it from the original data.

Comment: @jw9832hds some overheads are going to be unavoidable when threading, and there are other overheads around allocations and buffers that are going to be competing (although not catastrophically); personally the first thing I'd try here is using protobuf-net, but: I'm massively biased - but: this can't handle `object` : it wants typed data; if your `Hashtable` can actually be a `Dictionary<string,string>`, that would help immensely

Comment: @MarcGravell Unfortunatly I'm unable to use Dictionary since it's slower on lookups than Hashtable. I tried protobuf-net but Hashtable is not supported.

Comment: @JonasH No the code splits the hashtable into x amount of smaller hashtables meaning there will be 8 chunks and 8 threads created if ```int threads = 8;``` and each chunk will be 62500 in size.

Comment: Mind you: _"Important - We don't recommend that you use the `Hashtable` class for new development. Instead, we recommend that you use the generic `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` class. For more information, see [Non-generic collections shouldn't be used](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0006.md) on GitHub."_ - from [Remarks on Hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable?view=net-8.0#remarks)

Comment: _"I'm unable to use Dictionary since it's slower on lookups than Hashtable"_ - do you have a benchmark on that? I am inclined to doubt that, though I would have to do some research to build more confidence.

Comment: @Fildor I have a benchmark showing a much more complex set of metrics: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/843e08249726aa4a84c72045d5c0c528

Comment: @Fildor It seems that Dictionary is actually a bit faster than hashtable from my own test.

Comment: @MarcGravell I will try using Dictionary now instead and try protobuff since dictionary is faster.

Comment: @MarcGravell using Dictionary<string,string> + Protobuf is a lot faster but the multithreaded performance is still not what I expect. 8 chunks/threads is around twice as fast as 1 thread/chunk when I expect it to be closer to 8 times as fast.

Comment: @MarcGravell Awesome! Shows about what I would have expected.